# Laravel Vue, two way binding for slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inertiajs

Using Vue/Inertia.js I'm trying to make 2 price sliders, setting the min and max price values.

```
<div class="custom-slider">
                    <input
                        v-model="vMin"
                        type="range"
                        min="1"
                        max="500"
                        class="slider"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="custom-slider">
                    <input
                        v-model="vMax"
                        type="range"
                        min="100"
                        max="500"
                        class="slider"
                    />
                    <input v-model="vMin" type="number" class="input" />
                    <input v-model="vMax" type="number" class="input"  />
                </div>
```

I have 2 questions. Firstly I would like to know how to limit the slider value, so that the min value doesn't go over the max, and vice versa.

The v-models are a pair of props sent with page requests, so I am able to handle the back end issue this causes by having a watcher in the controller equalise the values if this happens, filtering the items properly, but the sliders themselves don't reflect this change.

```
watch([
vMin, vMax
], ([
    val1, val2,  data
]) => {
if(val1 > val2){
    val1 = val2
}else if(val2 < val1){
    val2 = val1
}

Inertia.get(window.location, { vMin: val1,  vMax: val2, filters: data,   }, {
    preserveState: true,
});
});
```

The second issue that I noticed is that for some reason, if one of the values goes below 100, the watcher decides that that one is higher value one.

I know that the solution is to implement two way binding, but so far I have failed miserably in all of my attempts to do that.

Does anyone have an idea what the solution here might be?